# how to loop files in the folders and subfolders

Tags: c#

I am having a problem writing the files in folders and subfolders .

For Example:- test is the main folder

1) C:\test\

and i want to read and write the subfolder files

2)C:\test\12-05-2011\12-05-2011.txt

3)C:\test\13-05-2011\13-05-2011.txt

4)C:\test\14-05-2011\14-05-2011.txt

my code is .

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string Path1 = @"C:\test";
        DoOnSubfolders(Path1);

        try
        {


            StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(Path1);
            string str = reader1.ReadToEnd();
            reader1.Close();
            reader1.Dispose();
            File.Delete(Path1);
            string[] Strarray = str.Split(new char[] { Strings.ChrW(10) });
            int abc = Strarray.Length - 2;
            int xyz = 0;
            while (xyz <= abc)
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] strarray1 = Strarray[xyz].Split(",".ToCharArray());
                    string SecName = strarray1[0];
                    string SecSym = strarray1[1];
                    int DT = int.Parse(strarray1[2]);
                    int TM = int.Parse(strarray1[3]);
                    float O = float.Parse(strarray1[4]);
                    float H = float.Parse(strarray1[5]);
                    float L = float.Parse(strarray1[6]);
                    float C = float.Parse(strarray1[7]);
                    double V = double.Parse(strarray1[8]);
                    double OI = double.Parse(strarray1[9]);
                    BTLReaderClass class2 = new BTLReaderClass();
                    BTLWriterClass class3 = new BTLWriterClass();
                    if (! Directory.Exists("C:\\Sample1"))
                    {
                        class3.CreateDirectory("C:\\Sample1");
                    }
                    else if (! File.Exists("C:\\Sample1\\RMaster"))
                    {
                        class3.CreateDirectory("C:\\Sample1");
                    }
                    class3.OpenDirectory("C:\\Sample1");
                    if (! class3.get_bSymbolExists(SecSym))
                    {
                        class3.AppendISecurity(SecSym, SecName, INTERVAL.Minute60 );
                        class3.CloseSecurity();
                        class3.CloseDirectory();
                        class3.OpenDirectory("C:\\Sample1");
                        class3.OpenSecurityBySymbol(SecSym);
                        class3.DataRec(DT, TM, O, H, L, C, (float) V, (float) OI);
                        class3.CloseSecurity();
                        class3.CloseDirectory();
                    }
                    else if (class3.get_bSymbolExists(SecSym))
                    {
                        class2.OpenDirectory("C:\\Sample1");
                        class2.OpenSecurityBySymbol(SecSym);
                        class2.SeekToEnd();
                        class2.Seek(-1);
                        class2.ReadDay();
                        int OldTime = class2.iSeTime;
                        int OldDate = class2.iSeDate;
                        float OldO = class2.dSeOpen;
                        float OldH = class2.dSeHigh;
                        float OldL = class2.dSeLow;
                        float OldC = class2.dSeClose;
                        double OldV = class2.dSeVolume;
                        double OldOI = class2.dSeOpenInterest;
                        class2.CloseSecurity();
                        class2.CloseDirectory();
                        if (OldTime != TM | OldDate != DT)
                        {
                            class3.OpenSecurityBySymbol(SecSym);
                            class3.AppendIData(DT, TM, O, H, L, C, (float) V, (float) OI);

                            class3.CloseSecurity();
                            class3.CloseDirectory();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            class3.OpenSecurityBySymbol(SecSym);
                            class3.LastRecord(DT, TM, O, H, L, C, (float) V, (float) OI);

                            class3.CloseSecurity();
                            class3.CloseDirectory();

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //MsgBox("Error" & ex1.Message)
                }
                xyz++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //MsgBox("Error" & ex.Message)
        }
    }
```

i am getting an error the error is Access to the path 'C:\test' is denied.

can anyone say me what i need to change in this code.

please help us

Thanks In Advance